# Class not found exception (org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable) thrown in a client of WLS 10

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, openjpa

I am developing an aplication using WLS 10
When i try to conect (lookup) to an EJB from a specific jar of my ear aplication, an exception of type "ClassNotFoundException" of the class "org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable" is thrown in the client

has anybody found a reason for this workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You very likely need **openjpa.jar** on the class path of the client.

Comment: I am using the wlfullclient.jar in the client, so it's suppose to use javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable interface

I even tryed your solution and the class that it's not able to find then is javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable

Comment: @user316689 Well, I don't know what OpenJPA is supposed to do but the fact is that it seems to add an import on `org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable` in your entities, so you'll need this class on the client side (and it isn't provided by wlfullclient.jar). What error do you get when you tried? Again a `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: Yes, my first thought was exactly yours, but when i added the openjpa.jar in my classpath i found that the exception throws in this moment was ClassNotFoundException of javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable thats is in the wlfullclient.jar. Obviously i tried with and without wlfullclient.jar and i have the same behaviour

Comment: It's working now. I don't know exactly what is the diference. I will search what i did to try to resolve my self (and others) the problem 
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @David Maybe a mistake on your side :)

Comment: maybe not i'm sure of that :) but i wanna know my mistake to ensure nobody else get as fool as me :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem than you and I couldn't catch how you solved it. Please may you re phrase your answer...

thanks in advance